# Block Google ads on localhost while in development mode

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net

I frequently have to update and test my small websites on my local machine.
The websites use google ads.

I used to manually disable and enable the ads on each and every page and this is very painful.

I want to disable all the google ads while I am testing the website on my local machine. How do I achieve this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After a few struggles, I found a basic solution to block all ads on localhost.
The only limitation is that this has to be placed in `master`file and all the files inheriting the master file will have ads blocked.

Paste the below script in your `master` file in `head` section before including any other scripts.

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
        //block google ads on localhost
        if (window.location.hostname === "localhost") {
            window.adsbygoogle = {
                enabled: true,
                loaded: true,
                push: function () {
                    return;
                },
                google_ad_client: "",
                enable_page_level_ads: true
            }
        }
    </script>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use adblocker enable it when you work on localhost and then disable it when you publish your site.

Comment: Yes i can but I am forbidden from installing any addons

Comment: what about creating your own extension? can you?

Answer (score 1):

There are two ways, you can develop your own Chrome extension that runs only on your chrome to hide Google Ads (which by the way have unique set of HTML so it is easy to pin point them and remove them).

Or you can make a link to a javascript file in the main template, that is always empty on the server (production), but locally it defines the css for Google Ads to be hidden. Again, Google Ads selectors are not so hard to pin point.

https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/getstarted

Here is a plnkr code for that purpose

manifest.json

```
http://plnkr.co/edit/wPxuO0vndIBMTz1ajMyJ?p=preview
{
  "name": "Walnut",
  "description": "hide ads",
  "version": "2.0",

 "content_scripts": [
    {
      "matches": ["https://*.facebook.com/*","http://localhost:8080/*"],
        "css": [ "remove.css" ],
        "js": ["remove.js"],
      "run_at": "document_start"
    }
  ],
  "manifest_version": 2
}
```

remove.js

```
// you can also make the removal periodical in case the Ad provider keeps recreating itself
// here you can have more freedon to find elements that main contain certain part of a class name or id
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {

    var all = document.getElementsByTagName("*");

    for (var i=0, max=all.length; i < max; i++) {
      // check id and hide if it matches google-ad-*
    }
    setTimeout(function () {
        var ads = document.getElementsByClassName("example-suspected-class");


        if (ads.length == 1) {

            ads[0].remove();
        }
    }, 100);

    setInterval(function () {
        var ads = document.getElementsByClassName("example-suspected-class");

        if (ads.length == 1) {

            ads[0].remove();
        }
    },10000);


});
```

remove.css

```
/* setup any css you susspect would mean something to web page, examples */
#slot_TL1 {display: none!important;}
.vp-off .mb-list-ad {display: none!important;}
.vp-off .mb-list-ad * {display: none!important;}
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/wPxuO0vndIBMTz1ajMyJ?p=preview

Answer (score 0):

How about you have a flag in the config file where you can set a value to it when you are developing/testing locally.

Comment: We don't have that for the older projects and that is why i have to manually comment/uncomment ads

Comment: It doesn't have to be a config file, it could be any file(ini, txt), or just declare some global variable in the project, just make sure you set it to the correct value on each release.